# How to CAST double precision to string in PostgreSql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I am wondering how I CAST double precision to string or if you can do it?
the code I am working with is:

```
select 
(select name from locations loc where loc.type = 9 and id in (select id from locations where l.parent = loc.id)) BayName,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT l.name), ', ') TroughName,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT b.name), ', ') BatchName,
    **ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(CAST(sum(case when m.type = 1 and l.name = l.name  then m.amount end)-
    sum(case when m.type = 3 and l.name = l.name  then m.amount else 0 end)-
    sum(case when m.type = 5 and l.name = l.name  then m.amount else 0 end) AS varchar(200))), ', ')** MotherTotalAmount
from batches b 
left outer join phases p on b.id = p.batch
left outer join movements m on b.id = m.batch
left outer join locations l on m.location = l.id
where b.type = 2 and p.type = 13 and b."isActive" = 'true' and m.type in (1, 3 , 5) and (select name from locations loc where loc.type = 9 and id in (select id from locations where l.parent = loc.id)) is not null
group by (select name from locations loc where loc.type = 9 and id in (select id from locations where l.parent = loc.id)), l.name
```

The out put should look like batchname below for the MothersTotalAmount field instead of giving just the total

```
"bayname"   "troughname"    "batchname" "mothertotalamount"
"13N"   "4" "BLW-002M, CHG-002M, GEL-002M, GJE-003M, GLU-002M, GOG-002M, GSC-002M, GTH-001M, R4-001M, SOD-002M" 89
```

I need to have the sum total as a string, in order to have the same output as ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT b.name), ', ') BatchName, unless there is a different way of do it?

Comment: Unrelated, but: `ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT l.name), ', ')` can be simplified to `string_agg(distinct l.name, ',')`

Comment: `select pg_typeof(10.5::float8::text); text`